# How do I print the matched string?

Tags: c, regex, flex-lexer, lex

I'm really not familiar with lex/flex. 
I'm trying to debug some legacy flex code. 
I want to see the text that was matched by a particular rule.

eg.

```
[a-z]*      {"some C code"  "need to print the string that matched this rule"}
```

eg. 
if `johndoe@xyz.com`   is the input, I need to print the matched string, i.e. `johndoe`

I tried printing `yytext`, but it shows me only the first character.

Comment: how are you trying to print?  Can you add the code snippet?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're trying to debug, and you're using `flex`, then you probably want to use the `-d` option when you translate your flex input into `C`. That will build a debugging scanner which will automatically report all rule matches (as well as other events).

For more details, see the [flex manual](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Debugging-Options.html)

If you really want to insert `printf` statements, this should work fine:

```
printf("The matched text is <%s>\n", yytext);
```

Comment: Thanks! the -d option really helped, the problem was with my regex not with yytext :)